# How to use -fPIC and -fPIE GCC options correctly

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, elf

I have a directory structure like this

```
dir1
    one.c
    two.c
dir2
    three_main.c
    four.c
```

I need to create a shared library `libdir1.so` out of all **c** files in `dir1`
and an executable `my_exe` out of all **c** files in `dir2` along with the `libdir1.so`

I am creating the **.so** and the **executable** in two steps.

```
.so step1:    gcc -c -fPIC -g -O2 -pthread -o one.o one.c
              gcc -c -fPIC -g -O2 -pthread -o two.o two.c
.so step2:    gcc -shared -g -O2 -pthread -o libdir1.so one.o two.o


exe step1:    gcc -c -fPIE -o three_main.o three_main.c
              gcc -c -fPIE -o four.o four.c
exe step2:    gcc -Wall -g -L -ldir1 -o my_exe three_main.o four.o
```

Now my questions are....

1. Should I use **-fPIC** and **-fPIE** in `step1` or `step2` or in both?
2. Can I use **-fPIE** in `step2` in creating the **.so** file?
3. Can I use **-fPIC** in `step1` in creating the **executable**?
4. How can I use **RELRO** compiler option in creating both **.so** and **executable**?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I use -fPIC and -fPIE in step1 or step2 or in both?

No. The way you currently build the `.so` and the binary is correct / optimal.

> Can I use -fPIE in step2 in creating the .so file?

You could, but you shouldn't: `-fPIE` is a compile-time option, and you are only linking in step2. If you pass `-fPIE` to the link, it will be ignored.

> Can I use -fPIC in step1 in creating the executable?

You could, but this will create sub-optimal code in the executable.

> How can I use RELRO compiler option in creating both .so and executable?

Add `-Wl,-z,relro`.

> should I be using -z,now along with -Wl,-z,relro to be effective?

Yes: for maximum hardening, you should. `-Wl,-z,relro` without `-z,now` is not *ineffective*, but it is *less* effective. [Details](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/hardening-elf-binaries-using-relocation-read-only-relro).

> can I use relro for both binary and .so?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer,  should I be using `-z,now` along with `-Wl,-z,relro` to be effective? and can I use `relro` for both **binary** and **.so**?